# What are the 'type' values that can be used with the _script sorting option?

Tags: elasticsearch

From their documentation, here's an example:

```
{
  "query" : {
    ....
  },
  "sort" : {
    "_script" : {
        "type" : "number",
        "script" : {
            "inline": "doc['field_name'].value * factor",
            "params" : {
                "factor" : 1.1
            }
        },
        "order" : "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

But they never mention what are the different values that you could use on the "type" field.

Comment: Just so you know, scripts are really slow. I'd make a new field with the original value * factor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"number"` and `"string"` are the only two values that can be used for `type` parameter.

You can find it [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/07aad5b7788f6048d860d27e8c92dad31fcbe5cc/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/sort/ScriptSortParser.java#L161) in the source code.